# How to download more than one video with youtube-dl in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, downloads, youtube-dl

How do I download more than one video with

```
 $ youtube-dl
```

in Ubuntu 14.04? Even if I open another terminal and try to download a different video, it shows first downloading progress.

Is there any way to queue up downloads ?

Comment: as you have said that the second terminal also shows the same progress bar, i guess you should update the youtube-dl, the best option is try installing youtube-dl from pip

Answer (score 2):

you can download the whole youtube playlist with youtube-dl as

```
youtube-dl -cif <quality number> <url>
```

where,

```
  c = continue the video download if it was paused
  i = ignore errors
  f = the quality of the video
```

this will download the whole playlist and if you closed and later started downloading it will download from where it was interrupted

and you can always do

```
man youtube-dl
```

Answer (score 2):

As bolzano said, you just run youtube-dl with whatever options you're using, and then as many links as  you want seperated by spaces.

For example:

```
youtube-dl -cif <link> <link> <link>
```

Would queue up the three youtube videos for download.